# mailx issue while sending the output in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I've written a code where it will check the successful execution of the last run command and will mail the output with the subject.

```
#!/bin/ksh

SCHEDULER ID="abc123"
RUNNUM_INFO="1212"
DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
FILE="OX_{DATE}.txt"

/usr/bin/ftp -n 93.179.136.9 << !EOF!
user abc passwd
cd "/0009/Codici Migrazione"
bin
get $FILE
bye
!EOF!


if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
echo "Activity completed. \n
SCHEDULER ID : $SCHEDULE_ID \n BILL_RUN_NUM: $BILL_RUNNUM_INFO \n DATE: $DATE" | mailx -r "ashish@xyz.com" -s "Activity Completed - $DATE"
exit 0
fi
```

But, on executing the script, I'm getting error:

```
The flags you gave are used only when sending mail.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a destination/To: email address, eg:

```
mailx -r "ashish@xyz.com" -s "Activity Completed - $DATE" recipient@abc.com
```

You'll also want to review your variables as you've got a couple issues:

1 - SCHEDULER ID="abc123" => not a valid variable; then it looks like you're trying to reference it later via $SCHEDULE_ID (valid variable name, but different spelling)

2 - RUNNUM_INFO => valid variable name, but later you try to reference it via $BILL_RUNNUM_INFO (valid variable name, but different spelling)

Comment: Thanks :-) had not added destination email address, have now corrected variable names.

Comment: Can I give multiple email ids in the destination? Like below:              mailx -r "ashish@xyz.com" -s "Activity Completed - $DATE" recipient1@abc.com recipient2@abc.com recipient3@abc.com        will it work?

Comment: Yes, you can stipulate multiple recipients/destinations; have you tried it?
 ("When in doubt, try it out!"); I believe mailx will accept the addresses separated by a space or comma (not at a unix command line at the moment)